# git diff to compare remote and local branches does nothing

Tags: git

I'm trying to view differences between my local master branch and the remote origin/master branch. I've read several such questions here and tried all the following options.

```
c:\>git diff master..origin/master

c:\>git diff origin/master master

c:\>git diff origin/master..master

c:\>git diff master origin/master

c:\>git log -p HEAD..FETCH_HEAD
```

Silence. Nothing.

I've tried them before and after doing `git fetch` and `git fetch origin`. To be clear: my local branch is different from the remote. `git diff` shows my changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *To be clear: my local branch is different from the remote. git diff shows my changes.*

If `git diff` is showing changes then your local branch likely *isn't* different from the remote because you haven't committed or even staged your changes yet.

`git diff` shows the difference between the working copy (ie. what's sitting on the disk) and the staging area. Various flags change what's being diffed. `git diff --staged` shows the difference between what you've staged and HEAD, it shows what is about to be committed.

```
WORKING COPY           STAGING AREA                    HEAD
       <--- git diff --->     <--- git diff --staged --->
```

I made [a cheat sheet which illustrates this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8332480/Git%20Cheat%20Sheets.pdf).

So if `git diff` is showing you have changes, those changes have not been staged nor committed. A `git status` should confirm.

To see what differences your *working copy* has vs `origin/master` use `git diff origin/master`.

Comment: Surely I should not have to commit to see the difference between my code and the remote code? `git diff origin/master` also returns/shows nothing.

Comment: @Marc You don't have to commit, use `git diff origin/master`. As for why that isn't showing a change either, showing us a `git status` will clear a lot of things up.

Comment: Minor tweak to cheat-sheet: `HEAD` normally points to the branch name itself, which then points to the commit. It only points directly to a commit for detached HEAD.

Comment: @torek Hmm. While that's true, does knowing that detail make a practical difference in how one uses Git? I like to keep the user's model of how Git works as stripped down as possible.

Comment: I'd say "no difference in use, but it explains *why* it's called a detached HEAD"...

Comment: @torek And `.git/HEAD` is how Git knows what the current branch is. Ok, I'll patch it in.

Comment: Must admit I'm still confused. I did `git add` and now all commands (diff, status) are silent. I just wanna know if what I am about to commit and push is different from the remote repo.

Comment: I think I must have done a `pull` recently which meant my working copy was the same as the remote and then when I did `add` it overwrote the staged changes. I now have nothing to commit and guess I have lost my changes. Sheesh!